# Spock interaction test takes precedence over exceptions

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock

Why does the following test fail with "too few calls" instead of the actual exception that is thrown inside the `do` method before the mocked method could be called?

Is there any way to change this behavior?

```
@Test
def "Should Create"() {
    when: "We do stuff"
    this.someStuff.do()

    then: "Should not get exception"
    notThrown(Exception)

    and: "Should send mail"
    1 * mailSession.send(_, _, _, _, _, _, _)
}
```

Comment: Too little info to diagnose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have discovered a bug. Please file an issue at http://issues.spockframework.org.

PS: Instead of `notThrown(Exception)`, it's more common to use `noExceptionThrown()`. Instead of `1 * mailSession.send(_, _, _, _, _, _, _)`, it's more common to use `1 * mailSession.send(*_)`. `@Test` is a JUnit annotation that has no effect on Spock.

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact type of exception thrown in `do()` method?

Possibly you may want to use `noExceptionThrown()` Spock method instead of `notThrown(Exception)`.

Comment: Not sure right now but I think the type of exception doesn't matter. The thing is when the exception is thrown, `mailSession.send` doesn't get to be called so both parts "then" and "and" are appliable but the "Should send mail" takes precedence. If I put the "Should send mail" check away, the "Should not get exception" part is handled correctly.

Comment: There is not enough details posted to tell, honestly.